# Access Data Directory in Openshift with URL

Tags: jsp, url, directory, openshift, symlink

I want to access a data directory in OpenShift.
I created a folder called `uploads` and I also created the symlink using putty,
still I cant access the file and it shows a 404 page.

Can anybody tell me the process in detail (step by step),
as I recently started working with OpenShift.

Also, whenever I update the repository using a git client it deletes the symlink.
I'm working on a maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps which I followed:

1. `cd <openshift deploy dir in my local system>`
2. `touch .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
3. `vi .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
4. Pasted the following code `ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}images /var/lib/openshift/<app-id>/jbossews/webapps` in the file. Note: images dir is already present in the data dir on the openshift server.
5. `chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
6. `git add .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
7. `git commit -a -m "added deploy"`
8. `git push origin`

I was able to access the images folder here: https://app-url/images

Hope this helps

Comment: I followed the above instructions. It's still giving me 404 error. Is something else required to do except these above steps?

Answer (score 3):

Create the symlink in a deploy action hook to prevent the symlink from being overwritten.

In `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This deploy hook gets executed after dependencies are resolved and the
# build hook has been run but before the application has been started back
# up again.

# create the uploads directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ]; then
    mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads
fi

# create symlink to uploads directory
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}webapps/
```

See [line 67 of the WordPress QuickStart](https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy#L67) as an example.

Comment: i tried it and it didn't work
and it didn't create symlink,  i checked it in ftp client

Comment: My fault - was in a hurry the other day. Answer updated.

Comment: How would I access it through a html image path?

Something like: <img src="/webapps/myimage.jpeg">?