# OpenShift Access DATA_DIR with url using symlink

Tags: maven, url, openshift, datadirectory

I created a Maven project in OpenShift. I want to access file in `data/uploads` folder for this.

I created deploy in `.openshift\action_hooks`

```
ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}src/main/webapp
```

But it won't create symlink, and even if I create a symlink directly it still can't access with url. Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Data Directory in Openshift with URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914046/access-data-directory-in-openshift-with-url)

Answer (score 0):

My fault on the original answer. The uploads directory has to exist before you create the symlink to it:

```
if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ]; then
    mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads
fi
ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}src/main/webapp
```

Comment: of course i created the uploads directory,
and create a symlink using putty.
in ftp or putty the symlink works correctly but with url it didn't