# OpenShift Java - Use image out of Data dir

Tags: java, jsp, openshift

I'm trying to create an upload-image button and afterward showing the image on a different jsp page.

I want to do this by uploading into the `app-root/data/images` folder. This works with the below filepath: `filePath = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + "images/";`

But how can I show this image on my jsp? I tried using:

```
<BODY>

    <h1>SNOOP PAGE</h1>
    <a href="profielMijnBedrijf.jsp">Ga weer terug</a>
    <% String filepath =  System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + "images/"; 
     out.println("<img src='"+filepath+"logo21.jpg'/>");

    %>

    <img src="app-root/data/images/logo21.jpg"/>
</BODY>
```

Both these options don't work. I also read that I need to create a symbolic link. But when I'm in my `app-root/data` or `app-root/data/images` or in `app-root` the command `ln -s` returns `missing file operand`

The logo21.jpg does show up in my Git bash

Comment: Using the `System.getenv` creates the link to the image with the ssh-key in it.

Comment: Did you try to have the symlink created using the `deploy` action hook as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29924096/5400813)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@developercorey is right (gave you +1 ), I just feel the need to explain why:

- Your uploaded images ends up in a folder on your **server**
  (`String filepath =  System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + "images/"` is the folder path in the server).
- Your rendered HTML `"<img src='"+filepath+"logo21.jpg'/>` get sent to the **client** (the user's browser), with the server's `filepath` url.
- Obviously, when the user's browser try to locate the image, using the path of the server, which doesn't exist on the local machine, it won't work.

The best solution, as @developercorey suggested, is to add a new servlet or a filter to serve photos from the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` folder:

- You'll have a new url mapped to the servlet serving your photo, something like `http://your-server/uploaded/`
- And you can use `<img src="http://your-server/uploaded/logo21.jpg" />` in your jsp.

Here's the snippet from [How-To: Upload and Serve files using Java Servlets on OpenShift](https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift?noredirect)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet(name = "uploads",urlPatterns = {"/uploads/*"})
@MultipartConfig
public class Uploads extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2857847752169838915L;
    int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            InputStream is = request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream();
            String fileName = getFileName(part);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + fileName);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = is.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
            is.close();
            os.close();
            out.println(fileName + " was uploaded to " + System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR"));
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String filePath = request.getRequestURI();

        File file = new File(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + filePath.replace("/uploads/",""));
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = input.read(bytes, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
            output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            output.flush();
        }

        input.close();
        output.close();
    }

    private String getFileName(Part part) {
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim()
                        .replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to serve user uploaded images that you are storing in your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR would be to use a servlet as described here: https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift?noredirect

This servlet basically takes the path/name of the image that is being requested, reads it from the filesystem and then serves it to the requester.

Answer (score 1):

The `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` directory is not web-accessible. You can make images stored in the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` (aka `app-root/data`) directory web-accessible by creating a symlink to them from the publicly accessible `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`.

For one-time use, as a proof of concept:

```
rhc ssh -a <your_app_name> -n <your_namespace>
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}images ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}images
```

You should now be able to access `logo21.jpg` at https://<your_app_name>-<your_namespace>.rhcloud.com/images/logo21.jpg, or `<img src="/images/logo21.jpg"/>`.

The contents of the `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` are overwritten when you push changes, so you'll want to create the symlink with a deploy hook to re-create it each time you deploy. In `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This deploy hook gets executed after dependencies are resolved and the
# build hook has been run but before the application has been started back
# up again.

# create the images directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}images ]; then
    mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}images
fi

# create symlink to uploads directory
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}images ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}images
```

Comment: Hmmmm... this probably isn't going to work for JSP... you actually are going to have to serve the images =\

Comment: I don't even have any file in `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy` . How can I generate these or what extension does `deploy` need to have?

And what do you mean by 'serve the images'?

Comment: See the response from @developercorey

Comment: @Ivaro18: Even if this is an quite old question, see [Action Hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) for more information about this topic. You just have to create a new file "deploy" (no extension needed) and push it. On each deploy (e.g. triggered by a `git push`) this action hook will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file to the DATA DIRECTORY, then copy the file from the DATA DIRECTORY to any folder in the HOME DIRECTORY.

Thereafter you should be able to reference the image as usual in your page but it appears Openshift only displays items from a previous deployment or git push, therefore perhaps it is best to save the file in a database then read it directly from that database.